# potential free output signal with AC as input (no mechanical relay)

Tags: switches, relay, triac, low-voltage

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I have a a bunch of 24vac actuators running of a 24vac XFR. The actuators themselves are controlled by a thermostat. What I need is a isolated 0v signal when any of them turn on plus a LED indicator for each one.
[image]

What I have in mind right now is simple AC to DC using full bridge rectifier/smoothing caps for each actuator> for each actuator have a FET with 2 outputs, one for indicator led and one for the signal.

I've looked into analog switches, SSR's and triac's but feel like those may be incorrect for application. Is there some other specialized IC for this?

Comment: I need clarification. "No mechanical relay" + "dry contact" = (???) ... I tend to think "dry contact" = "mechanical relay". But then my experience is limited and so is my vocabulary, I fear.

Comment: My experience is probably more limited, edited OP for now. Basically need isolated switching on output. There will be no load on the switching output side rather just a jumper that acts like a signal. I understand this is easily achievable with a mechanical relay but there has to be a more efficient way to do this over bulky relays.

Comment: In particular, do you mean ***galvanically isolated***???

Comment: Yes, that's the term.

Comment: Something like a pc817 optocoupler with a resistor and diode? You could work an LED into that was well.